# Stalling Mazda CX-5 Skyactiv-D

Tags: engine, mazda, stall, hesitation, cx5

I recently imported a used 2016 Mazda CX-5 AWD Skyactiv-D which seems to have had a problem before it was sold. The car does not have any DTCs stored in the ECU nor does it have any pending codes. I noticed that it drives OK until you Rev it up, e.g. when you need to accelerate up a hill, then it starts jerking, as if the engine is being starved of fuel. Also when cruising on the road, it feel like it's lagging, as if something is dragging the vehicle backwards, or brakes are being applied. After driving for several days, it doesn't start at all. It just cranks but doesn't start.

Here's some data that I captured using FORScan
https://pasteboard.co/zA1kaHtxb8eS.jpg

Has anyone experienced this kind of problem?

Comment: Have you checked the fuel pressure? You'd need to check it running as well as off.

Comment: @PAULSTER2 I did check the fuel rail pressure and boticed that it drops suddenly, causing the vehicle to jerk. What causes the drop is unclear. See https://pasteboard.co/zA1kaHtxb8eS.jpg

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I'd suggest you've got a problem with either the fuel pump not working correctly (not providing the correct amount of fuel or in the process of dying) or the fuel filter is plugged. Either way, your description of losing power and or stalling seems to be a fueling issue.